# Make generated messages visible for an IDE

Tags: ros, python, message, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working with Pycharm and since I started using catkin, Pycharm can't find my msg files anymore and my program is full of red underlines making it difficult to distinguish between true and false errors. As example the following import will seem to Pycharm as "unresolved reference to mypackage.msg"

```
from mypackage.msg import *
```

This makes sense since the build is made out of source and all msg files are generated in the devel/share folder. How can I fix that and make my IDE find the necessary files automatically?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187618/make-generated-messages-visible-for-an-ide/) by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3339 on 2014-07-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In general, the right solution to this is to source your workspace's setup.bash file and then start your IDE directly from that shell, rather than trying to launch it from the GUI.

If that works well, you can usually create a custom launcher icon which sources your workspace's setup.bash file and then runs your IDE; the QtCreator instructions describe how to do this, and it shouldn't be hard to adapt it to another IDE. See the [IDEs Page](http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs) and the [QtCreator Section](http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs#QtCreator). Note that the instructions there assume that your bashrc sources the setup file for your workspace by default.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2014-07-27**:
Thanks, creating a .desktop file like QtCreator solved it. where the most important line is :
Exec=bash -i -c pycharm %F